# Testing for GUI in .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, gnome

Is there a good way to test whether I am logging into a text shell or starting a GUI session in my .bashrc?  For example, to set my editor to gedit if in gnome and emacs if using a command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `DISPLAY` variable will be set if you're logged in to an X session.

Edit: So, this (untested) code should work:

```
[ -n "${DISPLAY}" ] && export EDITOR=gedit || export EDITOR=emacs
```

**Fixed based on comments.**

Comment: Actually, you need to either leave off the -z or swap the editors.

Comment: FYI. [ is actually a command. If you're using bash, the preferred method is [[.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash conventions:

```
if [[ $DISPLAY ]]; then
    export EDITOR=gedit
else
    export EDITOR=emacs
fi
```